# How to get text with no class/id using selenium/python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of variables (date, size, medium, etc.) from this page (https://www.artprice.com/artist/844/hans-arp/lots/pasts) using python/selenium.

For the titles it was easy enough to use :

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sln_lot_show")
      for title in titles:
          print(title.text)
```

However the other variables seem to be text within the source code which have no identifiable id or class.

For example, to fetch the dates made I have tried:

```
dates_made = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6']/p[1]")
          for date_made in dates_made:
              print(date_made.get_attribute("date"))
```

and

```
dates_made = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6']/p[1]/date")
           for date_made in dates_made:
               print(date_made.text)
```

which both produce no error, but are not printing any results.

Is there some way to this text, which has no specific class or id?

Specific html here :

......

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
  <p>
   <i><a id="sln_16564482" class="sln_lot_show" href="/artist/844/hans-arp/print-multiple/16564482/vers-le-blanc-infini" title="&quot;Vers le Blanc Infini&quot;" ng-click="send_ga_event_now('artist_past_lots_search', 'select_lot_position', 'title', {eventValue: 1})">
        "Vers le Blanc Infini"
   </a></i>
   <date>
    (1960)
   </date>
  </p>
  <p>
   Print-Multiple, Etching, aquatint,
    <span ng-show="unite_to == 'in'" class="ng-hide">15 3/4 x 18 in</span>
    <span ng-show="unite_to == 'cm'">39 x 45 cm</span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the desired output? Also make sure you've the appropriate permissions to scrape the said website.

Comment: Sure. I'm just looking to print a simple list of the dates for each piece in the console, but haven't seen elements with no class/id before

Comment: You can write an example so we know your goal.

Comment: dates_made = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6']/p[1]/date")
           for date_made in dates_made:
               print(date_made.text)

I think that this should print something like:

1960
1954
1974
1934
etc (just examples)

Comment: Are `dates` the only data missing? Tip: you can use a **single** back tick   `` somecode `` to surround code blocks, end it with another back tick. It helps readability

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, `dates` is in the source code that I provided, but the program either isn't recognising the xpath, or it isn't printing it for some reason. I think because its just text with no class or id

Comment: try `p[0]` instead of `p[1]`, you need the **first** `p` tag (`[0]`), **not the second** (`[1]`)

Comment: Tried this with various methods, still not printing in the console and no error message

Comment: Try `//div/p/date/text()` xpath

Comment: Unfortunately still not printing

Answer (score 0):

Progressive mode, below Javascript will return you two-dimensional array (lots and details - 0,1,2,8,9 your indexes):

```
lots = driver.execute_script("[...document.querySelectorAll(".lot .row")].map(e => [...e.querySelectorAll("p")].map(e1 => e1.textContent.trim()))")
```

Classic mode:

```
lots = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lot .row")
for lot in lots:
    lotNo = lot.find_element_by_xpath("./div[1]/p[1]").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    title = lot.find_element_by_xpath("./div[2]/i").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    details = lot.find_element_by_xpath("./div[2]/p[2]").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    date = lot.find_element_by_xpath("./div[3]/p[1]").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
    country = lot.find_element_by_xpath("./div[3]/p[2]").get_attribute("textContent").strip()
```